# Bathtub Spout Dripping Sounds: Ways to reduce sound temporarily

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, water, spout

I have a Bath tub spout that lightly drips water. A plumber is coming by to fix it next week. In the mean time, what is a good sound reduction method? Should I place a sponge or towel at the bottom drain (instead of hitting the hard bath tub)? The water drip rate is not even close enough to overflow the tub each day.

[image]

Comment: Putting something absorbent at the point the drip lands will work until it becomes saturated, then you'll just be replacing the slight 'ding' of the bath with a small 'splash' instead. Solar Mike's answer will prevent the 'drip' altogether & turn it into a very slow 'run'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hook a small towel on it so the drips are caught.

Like this…

[image]

Comment: Most tea towels / small towels have a hanging loop and that spout has a small handle on top that the loop can go over. Cleat enough?

Comment: Maybe @SolarMike is referring to the diverter knob?

Comment: I added the worst piece of photoshopping in history, by way of explanation… ;))